# Count the number of comparisons and the number of copies each sorting algorithm performs

Tags: java, comparison, sorting

In Java, how do I take Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, Shell Sort, and Quick Sort and make a counter to tell me how many times they preform a comparison or copy.

I have all of the sorters made I just don't know how to make a counter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple, unless I am much mistaken.

For X Sort:

```
private int copyCounter = 0;
private int comparisonCounter = 0;

public void XSort(){

     // Sorting logic start
     ....
     //Perform comparison operation
     comparisonCounter++;
     ....
     //Perform copy operation
     copyCounter++;
     ....
     //Sorting logic ends

     //Print the values of copyCounter here
}
```

Once your method completes execution you will have the required counts. Assuming you have all the sorts implemented as separate classes you will need to modify your sort method in individual classes as above.

Comment: really dumb question but then how and where do i display the counter and copy?

Comment: Also this is my bubble sort, where exactly should i put the counter and comparison for the best results?

public void bubbleSort( int [ ] num )
{
     int j;
     boolean flag = true;        int temp;
  

     while ( flag )
     {
            flag= false;
            for( j=0;  j < num.length -1;  j++ )
             
            {
             
                   if ( num[ j ] < num[j+1] )                    { temp = num[ j ];                           num[ j ] = num[ j+1 ];
                           num[ j+1 ] = temp;
                          flag = true;

Comment: If you just want to output the values on console then you can print them at the end of your sort method. Where to put comparisonCounter? Just before your if statement. {Basically you need to ensure that counter is incremented every time you perform the operation}

Comment: for bubble sort would copy and comparison be the same number?